# How to set auto IDENTITY For Temp Table in Order by Date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my code

```
SELECT IDENTITY(INT, 1, 2) AS Orderid , CODE , [DATE] , [TIME] INTO #Temp 
FROM Table1  ORDER BY CODE ,[DATE],[TIME]
SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Output from this code is here:

[image: Output for this code is here]

But I need the following output:

[image]

So what can I do ...

Comment: Can you share the reasoning behind your output

Comment: ya, I Bind  The time value in Every Day Calender based on the Orderid .

Comment: You can't do `identity` on `select`

Comment: @shawnt00 That's what I first thought when I saw this query. But it seems it works just in the way the OP describes it!

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Wow, all the documentation says it only works with `select...into`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method, aside from not generating sequence numbers partitioned by `CODE`, does not guarantee that records will be insert into `#temp` in the order they are selected.

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the sequence numbers during the `INSERT`:

```
SELECT 2 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE 
                              ORDER BY CODE,[DATE], [TIME]) - 1, 
       CODE, [DATE], [TIME] 
INTO #Temp 
FROM Table1  
ORDER BY CODE,[DATE],[TIME]
```

This will generate sequence numbers:

```
ID CODE,  DATE
--------------
1, 2210,  ... 
3, 2210,  ... 
5, 2210,  ...
1, 10484, ...
3, 10484, ... 
5, 10484, ...
7, 10484, ...
```

Comment: ThankYou...But I don't need 123...n  order .      I want to order by CODE,DATE ,TIME .  Such as First code (2210)  need 1,3,5...n   and Second  Code don't Start Continue of  First code (Like 7,9,11..n) . It must be start again 1,3,5...n Only ADD NUMBERS ,..

Comment: Can you post some sample data that adhere to your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CODE ,[DATE],[TIME])) AS Orderid  ........
```